# Oracle UTL_FILE setting wrong permissions

Tags: linux, oracle, plsql

I have NFS share being accessed by two user **oracle** and **tech1**. The files created by tech1 user are processed and copied by oracle user.

But the files copied and used by oracle user are with changed ownership, that means the files which were previously owned by tech1 user after copying done by oracle user are  changed with owner owner as shown below.

```
-rw-rw---- tech1 tech1 somefilename.txt
```

after

```
UTL_FILE.FCOPY ('MY_DOC',
'somefilename.txt',
'MY_DOC2',
'somefilename.txt-Original_file');
END;

-rw-rw---- oracle tech1 somefilename.txt
```

It is to be noted that oracle user is part of the group tech1, so it can access the file without ownership.
The directories have permissions as follows:
source:

```
drwxrwsr-x tech1 tech1 sourcedirectory
```

destination :

```
drwxrwsr-x tech1 tech1 destinationdirectory
```

How can I stop the oracle user from changing the ownership of the file while copying?
The same is the case with UTL_FILE.OPEN command.
It is to be noted that I cannot change the umask for oracle user as it will affect other applications in the cluster.

Comment: ["On UNIX systems, the owner of a file created by the FOPEN function is the owner of the shadow process running the instance. Normally, this owner is ORACLE."](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/UTL_FILE.html#GUID-5EBAFB68-DE09-4E7A-B092-39C4EDE3A2AA). As FCOPY opens the target file, that will apply too. I don't believe there's any way to change that, in Oracle or Linux. (setUID on a directory doesn't change how files are created under it, for example.)  You'd see the came thing if the `oracle` user did an OS-level `cp` command. Why is this a problem though?

Comment: I suppose that if the two users are defined on separate NFS clients, and each only exists on one of them, you *could* possibly use the same UID for both of them... not sure that sounds like a good idea though.

Comment: setUID enables us to create files with same group as the group of the directory as shown in the quesiton. Setting same UID for both user is not an option as oracle user has other application connected to it.

Comment: set*GID* on the directory maintains the group for files created under it; setUID on a file affects executables; setUID on a directory doesn't do anything (as far as I know) - I was just pointing out that it doesn't affect ownership of files created under it. Anyway... it's working how it's supposed to.